# Unable to run jar file on linux, works perfectly on Windows

Tags: java, linux, raspbian

I have really frustrating problem with running .jar file on my Raspbian.

I try to run in this way:

```
'java -jar dd.jar'
```

which works on Windows, but on Linux, i get "Could not find or load main class (..)" error.
I use Java 1.8 on both systems, I exported project as "executable jar", gave execute permissions for jar file on Raspbian.

Here is manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: Project.RPi.main.Main
```

(Yes, I know that there shouldn't by uppercase letters in the name of package)
Main class is in this location:

```
dd\Project\RPi\main\Main.class
```

What can be a reason of such error?

Edit: I realized, that it started to happen, when i added GUI made in JavaFx to program.

Comment: Did you transfer the jar to Linux correctly?  E.g. can you list of the contents of the jar using `jar tvf dd.jar` from a Linux shell?

Comment: Yes, i can list them. There are all files from my project.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/265245/how-do-i-run-a-jar-file-via-the-terminal .. Please see the references.

Comment: I don't see a connection., because it works on Windows, so I assume the Manifest file contains required data. But maybe I didn't understand what You wanted to show me.